# RuntimeError: This version of jaxlib was built using AVX instructions

Tags: jax

I installed jax and jaxlib via pip, but when I try import jax I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mod/CreateModels.py", line 11, in <module>
    import jax
  File "/home/au/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from jax import config as _config_module
  File "/home/au/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/config.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jax._src.config import config as _deprecated_config  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/au/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/config.py", line 28, in <module>
    from jax._src import lib
  File "/home/au/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/lib/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    cpu_feature_guard.check_cpu_features()
RuntimeError: This version of jaxlib was built using AVX instructions, which your CPU and/or operating system do not support. You may be able work around this issue by building jaxlib from source.
```

This is the version of jax/jaxlib:

```
au@cork:/mod$ pip show jax
Name: jax
Version: 0.4.23
Summary: Differentiate, compile, and transform Numpy code.
Home-page: https://github.com/google/jax
Author: JAX team
Author-email: jax-dev@google.com
License: Apache-2.0
Location: /home/au/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: ml-dtypes, numpy, opt-einsum, scipy
Required-by: 
au@cork:/mod$ pip show jaxlib
Name: jaxlib
Version: 0.4.23
Summary: XLA library for JAX
Home-page: https://github.com/google/jax
Author: JAX team
Author-email: jax-dev@google.com
License: Apache-2.0
Location: /home/au/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: ml-dtypes, numpy, scipy
Required-by:
```

I have an (old) Acer laptop - x86_64. I thought that should be supported?

Answer (score 0):

All released versions of jaxlib since v0.1.62 (released 09 March 2021) [require AVX support](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jaxlib-0-1-62-march-9-2021).

If you want to run JAX on older hardware without AVX support, you *may* be able to do so by building jaxlib from source using the flags mentioned there (see [building jaxlib from source](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html#building-jaxlib-from-source)). Be aware, though, that the JAX project has no test coverage on non-AVX chips, so you may still run into issues.

Related issue: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/9580.